# How to test trained classifiers for recognition

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-recognition, cascade-classifier

I have done some training already with OpenCV train_cascade. It went successfully. But i am wondering how can i test it without building a new app from scratch. 1. Are there any other application where can i put my classifier and can test a real time object recognition with it? 2. And is it possible to use more classifiers at the same time to recognize more objects?

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: There's a sample of cascade classifier detection in opencv

Comment: I have tested one with  the facedetect sample just replacing the classifier with my own. But don't know ho to use when i have 2 classifiers.